# Read command does not work inside if statement. in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

How to read a user input only on certain condition. Following code does not work in ksh:

```
if [[ $contract = "$fld1" ]];then
   read position?"Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format,m should be less than n "
fi
```

Code does not wait for user prompt in above condition

Comment: Consider using `set -x` to monitor the values of `$contract` and `$fld1` during execution. Since this is entirely valid code (at least in ksh93), the likely explanation is that they're not *truly* equal.

Comment: (...I have to wonder who upvotes a question without understanding the problem space well enough to know if the issue it identifies is genuine).

Comment: Above code works well in my ksh. @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for your comments on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36731484/5832518).

Comment: @Raju, no worries. BTW, before that answer was deleted I was going to amend a link in my comment to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, the POSIX spec for `test` and `[ ]`. Granted, `[[ ]]` is its own syntax (which is why it doesn't need to follow quoting rules), but for most purposes it's a superset. (The reason it's correct and appropriate for the right-hand side to be quoted in the question is one of the exceptions to that "most purposes" rule: If the right-hand side of `=` is unquoted in `[[ ]]` it's treated as a glob test, not a simple comparison).

Comment: @Raju, ...so I was actually a slight bit inaccurate when I said "implicitly quotes", as opposed to "implicitly suppresses glob expansion and string-splitting".

Answer (score 5):

The posted code works just fine under ksh.

```
$ contract=c
$ fld1=c
$ if [[ $contract = "$fld1" ]];then
> read position?"Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format,m should be less than n "                         <
> fi
Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format,m should be less than n 1-2
$ echo $position
1-2
```

In answer to hedgehog's comment, you might use a less confusing prompt like that one:

```
read position?"Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format, (m should be less than n) : "
```

Note that the `read variable?prompt` syntax is `ksh` specific. Under `bash` you'll use `read -p prompt variable`. A portable method usable on most Bourne syntax based shells would be `printf "%s" "$prompt" ; read variable`

Comment: actually your code works, but its not correct because it doesnt work properly, you only print the message, but the temrinal doesnt wait for the user to give reply........

Comment: damn i just saw it, it actually prints the line and expects the user to add input right aftet the echo?? thats just ugly and very confusing, even i, had to think for 3 minutes before i get it, think about a user, lol.....

Comment: There is no `echo`, this `read` syntax has always been supported by `ksh`. I don't get your comment about a user being confused as (s)he doesn't see the source code anyway, only the prompt.

Comment: i meant that they would be confused by the prompt, because the output is like this
`Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format,m should be less than n` and as you did it, were its says "than n" the terminal expects the user to add their input there, even i couldnt understand that it was asking me for input there, if you change the row though, like i do below it is correct and understandable. as you did it it seems like the terminal got stucked.... ffs correct code, bad solution. were i said echo on my second comment i meant the actual output not the command echo :)

Comment: I didn't wrote that prompt, the OP did. I agree that as it is written the prompt would be confusing for a user but the issue reported is the read command doesn't work, not the user is confused. Answer edited anyway with a better prompt.

Answer (score 1):

this is the working version of your code:

```
if [[ $contract = "$fld1" ]];then
echo "Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format,m should be less than n"
read position
fi
```

if you want the terminal to wait the user for a reply you have to add the echo and the read seperately.
This works fine for you.
This is the output:

```
Enter the position of Contract number in m-n format,m should be less than n
##cursor waiting here for an input##
```

Comment: This method is more portable, although you should have used `printf "%s` instead of `echo`, but it doesn't fix anything. The OP syntax already works fine under `ksh`.